# Unmarshall from an InputStream

Tags: java, jaxb

I have written simple object to Marshall. I am marshalling it to a `StringWriter` rather than a file. It works fine but I am unsure how would I unmarshall it.

This is the code I've written so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setId(1002);
    employee.setOccupation("Software Developer");
    employee.setSalary("56000");

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    marshaller.marshal(employee, writer);
    System.out.println("Object Marshalled Successfully");

    Conversion.unMarshallingObject();
}

public static void unMarshallingObject() throws JAXBException {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(writer.toString().getBytes());

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

    Employee employee = (Employee) unmarshaller.unmarshal(stream);

    System.out.println("Object unmarshalled successfully");
    System.out.println("**********************************");
    System.out.println(employee.getId() + " " + employee.getOccupation() + " " + employee.getSalary());

}
```

There are plenty of examples but all pass a file. I don't want any file. Is it possible to do it this way?

Thanks

Comment: For one thing, you know that when you create a *new* StringWriter it's empty, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal-java.io.Reader-) you can unmarshal from a `Reader` just fine - that includes from a `StringReader`.

```
 Employee employee = (Employee) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(yourString));
```

Comment: Where I would be reading it from? What is yourString in my case?

Comment: @Jaykumar It would be the string you want to read. If you don't have a string how are you expecting to read it?

Comment: This is what I need to understand. I can create a file suppose employee.xml and read it from. But, now I can marshall it without creating a file and I want to unmarshall it. This is the whole point.

Comment: @Jaykumar Where are you storing the marshalled object?

Comment: In writer. This is what I am assuming.

Comment: @Jaykumar Am I right in thinking you are confused about how to pass information between methods? A `StringWriter` lets you create a string as if you were writing to a file; you still have to do something with that string to get it to wherever you're using it. You can't just create another StringWriter and have it magically contain the same string you wrote to the other one.

Comment: Marshalling works fine, it just while unmarshalling. And, you are right how to get the reader?

Comment: @Jaykumar You get the generated XML using `String xml = writer.toString()`. You then create a reader using `new StringReader(xml)`. See [this IDEONE for running version of your code](https://ideone.com/XNTYpu).

Comment: Yup, I think this should do the trick. I'll divide them into two methods. Thanks Andrea.